Cannot restart nuxt: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options') / @nuxtJs recapctha
I have tried to install the nuxtjs/recaptcha modul on my nuxt.config.ts but i have seen any solution on the web for this problem and i get this error :
ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')               13:27:36

  at module.exports (node_modules/@nuxtjs/recaptcha/lib/module.js:8:13)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:2468:101)
  at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:4496:5)
  at async NuxtDevServer._load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:6875:5)
  at async NuxtDevServer.load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:6810:7)
  at async NuxtDevServer.init (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev2.mjs:6805:5)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev-child.mjs:98:5)
  at async runCommand$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.6aad497e.mjs:1648:16)
  at async runCommand$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.6aad497e.mjs:1639:11)
  at async runMain$1 (node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.6aad497e.mjs:1777:7)

I share with you my nuxt.config.ts and my package.json.

nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    "@nuxt/image",
    '@vesp/nuxt-fontawesome',
    'nuxt-swiper',
    ['@nuxtjs/recaptcha', {
      siteKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
      version: 3,
    }],
  ],



  fontawesome: {
    icons: {
      solid: ['envelope', 'close', 'bars'],
      brands: ['instagram', 'linkedin', 'github']
    }
  },

  build: {
    transpile: ['@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome']
  },

  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@300;500&display=swap'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],

  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/fontawesome.ts',
    '@/plugins/email.ts'
  ],

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      emailjsPublicKey: process.env.EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY,
      emailjsServiceId: process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
      emailjsTemplateId: process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
    }
  },
});



package.json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^4.4.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.8",
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.7.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/recaptcha": "^1.1.2",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.4",
    "nuxt-swiper": "^1.2.2",
    "three": "^0.167.1",
    "vanta": "^0.5.24",
    "vue": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@vesp/nuxt-fontawesome": "^1.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.77.8"
  }
}




I tried to change the place of options or to create a plugin for the recaptcha but  with any success.

I have found the problem. It's because i use Nuxt 3 and this module is planned for Nuxt2. I have added the  google recapctha script in my nuxt.config.ts
